# Great iPod Click Wheel Games for Kids

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano, games, children

My niece has got a used iPod nano (not the newest model); in the App Store are about 50 games for iPods with Click Wheel. What game can you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vortex and Pacman are quite good as well. They're listed in iTunes as 5th generation compatible (Sonic... is for 3rd, 4th and 5th generation devices). I've got a 30GB video capable iPod and they all work fine...

Comment: If I remember correctly, Vortex came preinstalled on my nieces iPod nano, and is played oftenly. In the end I bought her Bubble Bash which pleased her a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have fond memories of the [Sonic the Hedgehog](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGame?id=270226992&s=143441) game on older iPods :)